iOS App Store keeps installing TestFlight version of app instead of App Store version
I'm having an issue with an app installation on my iPhone where it keeps installing the latest TestFlight version instead of the public App Store version. Here are the details:

I initially installed version 1.24 of the app via TestFlight.
I then uninstalled both the app and TestFlight and tried to reinstall the app from the App Store, which should be version 1.6 (the current public release).
Despite this, the App Store keeps installing version 1.24, which is the TestFlight version.

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Uninstalled both the app and TestFlight.
Restarted the iPhone to clear any cached data.
Tried offloading and reinstalling the App Store app through Settings to clear its cache.
Reinstalled only the App Store version, but the device still downloads the TestFlight release.

Has anyone experienced this before? Are there additional steps I can take to reset the association to the App Store version? Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Have you tried removing testflight and your apple account that linked with testflight ? That is really strange situation

Does the icon on your phone have an orange dot?  If it does, it's TestFlight. If not then it's App Store.

TestFlight is a parallel App Store, so you could disable it by logging out. Or if you want to be really mean, create a test Apple ID, and login so there's no confusion.

But if you are in the App Store, you download the wrong build, I'd just contact Apple at that point. There's shouldn't be a reason a TF build would be delivered via App Store.
